# I see lots of ANRs because of google ads (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite) on the Moto G(8) Power Lite

Tags: google-ads-api, motorola

Many crashes are occurring on the Moto G(8) Power Lite device.

Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke interface method 'awo ahf.a()' on a null object reference

agd.onTransact (:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@232400001@232400000057.538171701.538171701:21)

[image]